# 2D array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays

#### Description:

This program will read a data file that will contain students’ scores for 5
Computer Science (CS) tests. Each student record will contain his/her last name, first
name, numeric student ID, student username, 5 test scores, average for these five scores,
and grade for CS course. The file will be processed by the program and will produce a
report.

#### The report contains seven parts:

1. The students’ usernames
2. The average score for each student’s five tests.
3. The grade for each student’s CS course.
4. The average CS scores for the class.
5. The total number of students with grades A, B, C, D, and F.
6. The sorted student names and IDs based on user choice: descending or ascending order
   of grades.
7. Search a student grade by entering student user name ID.
   (See the attached sample input and output for example.)

#### Specifications:

1. All input data will be in an input file. The name of the data file that will be used
   for your program MUST BE grade.dat. You may need to create your own
   version of grade.dat to test your program before you turn it in. You must also
   submit a printout of the contents of this test file when you submit this project.
2. The student user name is generated by the students’ names and ID numbers
   according to the following rule. The student user name will be the first two initials
   and the four digits of the student ID number. For example, for student John (last
   name), Doe (first name), with ID number 1122, his user name would be: jd1122.
   The user names are all lower cases.
3. Your program needs to use a structure to store the student information including
   last name, first name numeric student ID, student user name, 5 test scores,
   average for these five scores, and grade for CS course.
4. Your program needs to write at least three functions in your program: For
   example: find average, find grade, search score etc. 
   2
5. Your program needs to do input checking: (1) correct input choices for sorting:
   ascending or descending; and (2) correct format for user ids: first two are letters
   and last four are digits.

#### Requirements for Submission:

You must
submit your C++ source code, which is .cpp file through myClasses@SU, and hand
in:

1. Design/pseudocode/hierarchy chart. of your algorithm.
2. A printed copy of your source code.
3. Your set of sample input data files
4. Your set of sample screen outputs corresponding to each input data file.
5. Program report: state clearly if your program doesn’t work well. What’s the
   problem? Or anything you want me to know, for example, you get the help from
   other students. You can not copy others’ work. It is individual program
   assignment!
6. You will need to be ready to demo your project and ready to answer any questions
   related with the project.

#### Grading Rubric:

```
Algorithm design/Pseudocode 10
Correct outputs 20
Structures 20
Functions 10
File reading 10
Input checking 10
Searching and sorting 10
Readability/comments of program (including project report) 10
3
Sample Run
```

#### Sample Input File grade.dat contains:

```
Bonebrake Nicole 1111 90 85 50 78 85
Boyer Dennie 2222 100 90 99 89 88
Bozick Julia 3333 52 85 44 66 87
Carroll Sandra 4444 87 88 95 85 100
Creighton Sarah 5555 91 55 80 88 75
Everett Terry 6666 60 70 59 79 89
Freeman Andrew 7777 92 95 94 96 97
Fugett Brandon 8888 77 88 75 95 80
```

#### Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct StudentData
{
    string first;
    string last;
    int studentID;
    int exam1;
    int exam2;
    int exam3;
    int exam4;
    int exam5;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("grade.dat");
    StudentData students[8][8];
    file.close();
}
```

I am having trouble bringing the data out of the file and putting it into an array.

Comment: How could you think that we would do your homework?

Comment: I didnt, I dont want someone to do it for me, I just need a head start. I am reading my book and looking at my notes but she hasnt taught anything about 2d array of structs,

Comment: Your code declares a 2-D array of structs. But I don't see that as a requirement in the assignment (although I might have missed something, it's hard to read an unformatted wall of text).  A 1-D array seems more appropriate.

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
     {
      for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
      {
       file >> student;
       students[x][y] = student;
       cout << student << "     ";
      }
      cout << endl;
  
       }

Comment: You should have your exam variables in an array or vector instead of several individual ones. I assume they are exam grades? And I assume first is the first name? Pick descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct StudentData
{
    string first;
    string last;
    int studentID;
    int exam1;
    int exam2;
    int exam3;
    int exam4;
    int exam5;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    string temp;
    char fname[100];
    char lname[100];
    file.open("grade.dat");
    StudentData students[8];

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        getline(file, temp);
        sscanf(temp.c_str(),"%s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d", fname,lname,&students[i].studentID
               ,&students[i].exam1,&students[i].exam2,
               &students[i].exam3,&students[i].exam4,&students[i].exam5);
        students[i].first = fname;
        students[i].last =lname;
    }

    file.close();

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cout<<students[i].first<<" "<<students[i].last<<" "<<students[i].studentID 
        <<" "<< students[i].exam1<<" "<< students[i].exam2<<" "<< students[i].exam3
        <<" "<< students[i].exam4<<" "<< students[i].exam5<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand this until the for.

Comment: In the for loop I took a line from file in string type variable `temp`. Then I converted it to a C equivalent string by `c_str()` function. Then I parsed data with `sscanf()` function which is just like `scanf()` function in C except it takes input from first parameter string..

Comment: can I use int, if some of my array is a string?

Comment: @Sarah I could not get you. Can you please, exemplify to clarify your question?

Comment: I see that it says "for (int i =0; i<8, i++)", but my array has strings in it, for the names. Im trying different things but no matter what I try, its either and error or it outputs some huge negative number in my console.

Comment: @Sarah Did not I take array from input? Don't think `name` as array, rather think it as a variable of data type `string`, It would be easy to understand for you. However, why did you posted answer? People would give negative vote on it. Before that, remove the answer. and don't forget to accept answer if it answer your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, since all you need is a head start, here are some hints:

First of all, your assignment says nothing about 2d arrays, if you are doing it for extra credit or something - don't, it is not mandated neither by your assignment, nor by the actual task at hand.

Second - your problem at hand - reading the file. You should start by reading it one line at a time. The line contains the names, the id and the grades. Once you have the line, you can extract the fields, by say splitting the string at the spacebars. This will give you a string for every field. Then you can assign the student name fields to the strings. There is also a function that converts strings to integers - that will come in handy for the rest of the fields.

Just to make things look a little more professional, you might want to consider using a container class instead of a plain array, `std::vector` is a good candidate. Also, if you are going to be sorting, you might want to use pointers (preferably smart pointers) and dynamic memory allocation. Also, in order to be able to sort your array, you will need to write  functions which compare students based on different criteria. A container will give you an easy way to add and remove students, instead of some stiff static construct.

Every step of the way is already covered in answers here on SO, so all you need to get things done is search whenever you get stuck.